# React Native : Subviews of KeyboardAvoidingView have lag / move at different speeds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like them all the subviews to move in one clean motion, but if you look at the gif, you can see that the Text subview and the TextInput subview overlap and move at different speeds. It looks like the Text subview adjusts its position instantly where as the button and TextInput subviews adjust their position in more of an Ease in Ease out manner.

[image]

Main exported component

```
class SearchScreen extends React.Component {

    state = {search:""}

    render(){
        getArguments = {
            search: this.state.search
        }
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.searchTitle}>Search for a Movie in the OMDB Database</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.searchField} onChangeText={text => this.setState({search:text})} ></TextInput>
                <SearchButton navigation = {this.props.navigation} getArguments={getArguments}/>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        )
    }

}
```

Styling

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: '#C8FEFE',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    searchButton: {
      marginTop: 20,
      backgroundColor: '#24D9E8',
      borderRadius: 5,
      padding: 5
    },
    searchField: {
      backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      textAlign: 'center',
      width: 200,
      borderRadius: 5,
      margin: 20,
      height: 30
    },
    searchTitle:{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign:'center'
    }
  });
```

---

**Github**

[Full project on github](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/movieBrowser)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1: Quick fix for iOS**

You can wrap your elements in a View, which will make them react to keyboard the way you want:

```
// styles
contentContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
}

// SearchScreen
<View style={styles.contentContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.searchTitle}>Search for a Movie in the OMDB Database</Text>
    <TextInput style={styles.searchField} onChangeText={text => this.setState({search:text})} ></TextInput>
    <SearchButton navigation = {this.props.navigation} getArguments={getArguments}/>
</View>
```

However, this will only work on iOS. Keyboard works slightly differently on Android. So solution 2 is a more solid way to do things.

**Solution 2: Animations**

Keyboard avoidance is quite tricky, [Spencer Carli's article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580/) that Dominik referred to is a great resource for solutions using `KeyboardAvoidingView`. Those usually give you what you need. But if you want a smooth, controlled transition between keyboard states, you should use animations. The flow would go like this:

1. Add [Keyboard event listeners](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard#methods) to your component (`keyboardDidShow` and `keyboardDidHide`)
2. Wrap the content you want to move in an [`Animated.View`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#__docusaurus)
3. on `keyboardDidShow`, animate the y position of the `Animated.View` by the offset you want. The event returned (of type `KeyboardEvent`), along with the `Dimensions` API have all the measurements you need. Tip: use an `Animated.timing` animation with bezier [`Easing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/easing#methods) to control how the view moves.
4. on `keyboardDidHide`, repeat the animation but in the opposite direction.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 0}>
...
<KeyboardAvoidingView/>
```

You can try adding some offset to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely style it with flexbox, try styling your `container` like this: 
(it should move them at once, as flexbox will fit them on current width and height)

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure react-native is flexbox by default. My current styling for the container is     `container: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: '#C8FEFE',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }`

Comment: Also the default, but I tried it and nothing changed

Comment: and I think you also tried setting all children to 100% height and making them flex too

Comment: Making the children 100% doesn't make sense because their height shouldn't be 100% of it's parent, and everything is flex by default, I actually don't think you can change it to be not flex

Comment: I think I've found a solution here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580/ take a look at 6th gif there, I think it's what you are looking for